# Image rollover effect

Tags: css, css-animations

I am all new to CSS and CSS animation and I have been curious how to achieve the image rollover effects used here: http://riot.design/portfolio/

Anyone kind enough to show me how its done?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The URL doesn't load for me. This might be helpful for you: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/06/19/ideas-for-subtle-hover-effects/

Comment: You're after 3D transforms. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_3dtransforms.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Slide effect for a Picture you can use CSS3

HTML:

```
<div class="hover column">
        <div>
            <figure><img src="surce/pic01.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.hover figure img {
    margin-left: 30px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

That gives you a slide effect.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.media{
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}

.media img{
-webkit-transform: scale(1);
-moz-transform: scale(1);
-ms-transform: scale(1);
transform: scale(1);
transition: all ease .5s;
}
.media:hover img{
-webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
-moz-transform: scale(1.2);
-ms-transform: scale(1.2);
transform: scale(1.2);
}
.overlay{
background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: 1;
}
.media:hover .overlay{
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
}
.link{
position: absolute;
padding: 15px;
border: 1px solid #fff;
color: #fff;
transition: all .5s ease;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
.media:hover .link{
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="media">
<div class="overlay">
    <a href="" class="link">Link</a>
</div>
    <div class="media-image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is exactly what im looking for! but how about the image tint on hover and the button that appears in the middle? Thank you afelixj!